# Sizeof() of pointer pointing to NULL

Tags: c, pointers, sizeof

Following is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct abc
{
    char a;
    int b;
};

int main()
{
    struct abc *abcp = NULL;
    printf("%d", sizeof(*abcp));    //Prints 8

    /* printf("%d",*abcp);            //Causes program to hang or terminate   */

    return 0;
}
```

I understand that the size of struct is 8 due to structure padding. However, why is sizeof() of '*abcp' giving a value when 'abcp' is assigned NULL? 'abcp' when assigned NULL means that it is not pointing anywhere right? But, why I am getting an output for the above code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sizeof` is not a function and it doesn't evaluate its argument. Instead it deduces the type of `*abcp`, at compile time, and reports the size of that. Since `abcp` is a `struct abc*`, the type of `*abcp` is `struct abc` regardless of where `abcp` points.

Answer (score 6):

`sizeof` is an operator, not a function.

You would be reminded of this if you dropped the pointless parentheses, and just wrote it:

```
printf("%zu", sizeof *abcp);
```

This also uses the C99-proper way to format a value of type `size_t`, which is `%zu`.

It works since the compiler computes the size at compile-time, without ever following (dereferencing) the pointer of course (since the pointer doesn't yet exist; the program isn't running).

Answer (score 2):

From the C99 Standard

6.5.3.4/2

`The sizeof operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which may be an expression or the parenthesized name of a type. The size is determined from the type of the operand. The result is an integer. If the type of the operand is a variable length array type, the operand is evaluated; otherwise, the operand is not evaluated and the result is an integer constant.`

Answer (score 0):

Given `Type *var`, the following expressions are equivalent:

```
sizeof(Type)
sizeof(*var)
sizeof(var[N]) // for any constant integer expression N
sizeof(var[n]) // for any variable integer expression n
```

Each one of these expressions is resolved into a constant value **during compilation**.

So the value of `var` during runtime has no effect on either one of these expressions.

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof` simply returns the size of *abcp and this pointer has size 8 in your machine. It doesn't matter if the address stored in the pointer is valid or not (`NULL` is usually an invalid address).

Comment: 8 is _not_ returned because "this pointer has size 8".  8 is returned because that is the size of the structure pointer to by `abcp`.  To retrun the size of the pointer, code would use `sizeof abcp`.